# Active navigation menu rails and Anchestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories, ancestry

I used Ancestry gem to provide full categorization function to my website.

At this point I want to create navigation menu.

The idea, is like this.

I click on main category, it navigates to it, there I can see all subcategories. I click on one of them. Opens up other subcategories for example.

I want to be able to see on navigation bar like this

```
Main category name -> Subcategory name -> subsub category name -> Product name
```

Somethink like this, but I not sure how to search for it in google because English is not my native language.
Main idea is to be able to see the tree of the categories that are siblings and parents to the children categories :)

Does somebody could suggest something for me. :)

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and flexible **breadcrumbs for Rails.**

You need navigation menu to be seen as you navigate through on clicks.

Then use [breadcrumb navigation menu](http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/breadcrumbs_on_rails/docs/).

It is simpler to use and it gives you the navigation as you expect on your clicks wherever you go.

For installation and requirements, check out this:

https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails#readme

Comment: But its not possible to create such function without other plugins ?

Comment: Plugins contains the functionality to shorten your code and providing you the output without much hassle. Breadcrumbs is best for navigation menu. Just a few installation steps. Without plugins like breadcrumbs is just like you are implementing the same functionality which is already inside breadcrumbs. Then why not to reuse it. Try it out and you will see for sure.

Comment: . thank you , but I found some solution without other gems. :)

Comment: This is my solution!categories_controller.rb under show action  `@category = Category.find(params[:id])  @path = @category.path `

Comment: and under show.html.erb I have `<div class="nav_tree">
 <% @path.each do |path|%>
 
 <%= link_to (path.name), path %>
 
 <%end%>
 </br>
  </div>` It was easier then I thought.:)

Comment: How are you evaluating `@category.path` to get the path of the current page ? Did you added one more field called `path` in the categories table to achieve like this?

Comment: I did not changed anything in categoris table. I am using ancestry gem, that have built in methods that allows me to do that :)